# How do I write eloquent query for retrieving multiple rows who have max versions?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[image]

I want to write a query to retrieve rows who have a max version for their particular groups

For eg:
English Basic has 4 versions(test_id:1,2,4,7). But I want to retrieve the one with the max version
with this I also want to retrieve other such records of max version

I want this result

- Mom Basic 20 1(version)(id:5)
- Mom Intermediate 30 1(version)(id:6)
- English Basic 20 5(version)(id:7)

Thanks and Let me know if you have any doubts

---

Here is what I've tried:

I got the SQL query:

```
SELECT *, MAX(`version`) FROM `test` GROUP BY `test_name`,`sub_category`,`test_type`
```

But I am not able to properly write it in laravel (throws syntax error)

Here are my laravel tries:

```
$test = Test::selectRaw('*, MAX(version) GROUP BY `test_name` ')->get();
$test = Test::selectRaw('*')->groupBy('sub_category')->toSql();
```

and so on

P.S. Don't worry about the format of commas or quotes as I tried all the combinations with this. Just not able to figure out what is the write code

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what the problem is that you're facing.

Comment: The wording is very confusing, how do you define max version?

Comment: Max version is the max value in that column for a particular set of row like for a group like 1-English-Basic  has many records but i want the one with the latest/max version

Answer (score 2):

I did not try this one. But I think you can do this. What you meant by unique is not clear.

```
Test::where('version', Test::max('version'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

**Mysql**

```
select test_type,test_name,sub_category,time,max(version) as version 
from table_name group by test_name,sub_categoryorder by version ;
```

**Laravel**

```
$result=DB::select(DB::raw("select test_type,test_name,sub_category,time,max(version) as version 

 from table_name group by test_name,sub_categoryorder by version"));
```

[Check Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=174e7c0b2536227948f6fafe973ef11b)

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxVersion = Test::orderBy('version', 'desc')->first(); // gets the whole row
```

Comment: This I already know buddy but this only gives one record. I want to retrieve multiple records with max version

Comment: `$maxValue= DB::table('test')->max('version');
   $rows=DB::table('test')->where('version', $maxValue)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

$test = DB::select(DB::raw("
        SELECT * FROM test a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT test_type, test_name,sub_category,  MAX(version) AS maxversion
                    FROM test GROUP BY test_type,test_name,sub_category) b
        ON a.test_type=b.test_type
        AND a.test_name=b.test_name
        AND a.sub_category=b.sub_category
        AND a.version=b.maxversion"));

There is no way to easily translate this into eloquent if you could do it then please post it here. Also you need to make sql strict in your config->database file as false to run this as it has some issue with group by